# Magento remove & synchronize google base items by script in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am using magento 1.3.2.4 and my problem is that sync & deleting google base items one by one takes a long time using the control panel.

So I want to know how to create a script that I can use in command line that sync & delete all items listing on google base in magento. I need to be able to relist items too.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the information below is useful to you: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/63666/

Comment: The link offered by @anunay has a code posted by Turbo1 that went through several iterations (the thread is pretty long) -- it is the best script to achieve what you want. You will see that the most recent messages incorporate several functionalities to the original Turbo1 script, such as accounting for configurable items and time limited sales. This script can also be converted easily to run on Bing and The Find. Ideally, you would run this via a cron job on your server.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same script noted in @anunays answer, but with some modifications I made earlier today so that it would work on 1.4.x as well as include some of Google Merchant Center's required attributes.

I just set condition to "new" and availability to "in stock" as the original script filtered on active, visible products.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php-5.3
<?php
/**
 * Generate a google base feed for google product search
 *
 * The core magento backend Gbase functionality was not working for me, and it
 * is oft maligned (at least in 1.4x and before) in the Mage community
 */
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::App('default');
define('GOOGLE_BASE_FEED_TXT', MY_URL . 'var/export/google_base_feed.txt');

class Generate_Google_Base_Feed_Txt
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->handle = fopen(GOOGLE_BASE_FEED_TXT, 'w');
    }

    public function build() {
        $heading   = array(
            'id',
            'title',
            'description',
            'link',
            'image_link',
            'price',
            'brand',
            'product_type',
            'condition',
            'availability',
        );
        $feed_line = implode("\t", $heading) . "\r\n";
        fwrite($this->handle, $feed_line);

        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
        $products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
        $products->addAttributeToFilter(array(
            array('attribute'=>'manufacturer', 'notnull' => TRUE),
        ));
        $products->addAttributeToFilter(array(
            array('attribute'=>'name', 'notnull' => TRUE),
        ));
        $products->addAttributeToFilter(array(
            array('attribute'=>'image', 'notnull' => TRUE),
        ));
        $products->addAttributeToFilter(array(
            array('attribute'=>'url_key', 'notnull' => TRUE),
        ));

        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $product_data                 = array();
            $product_data['sku']          = $product->getSku();
            $product_data['title']        = $product->getName();
            $product_data['description']  = $product->getDescription();
            $product_data['link']         = MY_URL . $product->getUrlKey() . '.html';
            $product_data['image_link']   = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();
            $product_data['price']        = $product->getPrice();
            $product_data['brand']        = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
            $product_data['product_type'] = '';
            $product_data['condition']    = 'new';
            /* availability: required ("in stock", "out of stock", "preorder", "available for order") */
            // currently, we only use in-stock but in the future we should include everything and just set out-of-stock as such
            $product_data['availability'] = 'in stock';

            foreach ($product->getCategoryIds() as $_categoryId) {
                $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryId);
                // append categories
                $product_data['product_type'] .= $category->getName() . ', ';
            }
            $product_data['product_type'] = rtrim($product_data['product_type'], ', ');

            // sanitize data
            foreach ($product_data as $k => $val) {
                $bad              = array('"', "\r\n", "\n", "\r", "\t");
                $good             = array("", " ", " ", " ", "");
                $product_data[$k] = '"' . str_replace($bad, $good, $val) . '"';
            }

            $feed_line = implode("\t", $product_data) . "\r\n";
            fwrite($this->handle, $feed_line);
            fflush($this->handle);
        }
        fclose($this->handle);
    }
}

// test it, yo
$base_feed_txt = new Generate_Google_Base_Feed_Txt;
$base_feed_txt->build();
```